# difference between throughput and bit rate?

Tags: network-interface

Throughput and Bit rate seems to have the same meaning and also have same unit of bits per second. Then what is the exact difference between throughput and bit rate?

Comment: "Throughput" is not a well-defined technical term. Could you give some context or a link to the text you saw it in so we can see what you're asking about?

Comment: @sk1 Is this question in any way related to computer networking equipment?

Answer (score 13):

Here is my viewpoint:

**Bit Rate**:
The number of bit states, or binary information entities, that a channel can **transmit** per unit time.

***This is a design parameter.***

Thus, with a simple two-state channel such as a piece of wire that can be set to high or low voltage, and a driver (and channel capacity of the wire) that can and is configured to do such transitions 1000 times per second, the bit rate would be 1000 bits per second.

With encoding such as [Quadrature Phase Shift Keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Quadrature_phase-shift_keying_.28QPSK.29), on a suitable channel such as radio frequency, two bits can be transmitted per symbol or transition, thus at 1000 transitions per second, the bit rate would be 2000 bits per second.

---

**Throughput**:
The number of bit states of usable information, that can be successfully **received** over a channel per unit time.

***This is an observed, dynamic parameter*** with a fixed and a variable loss.

Thus, with the two-state wire example above, if there is an error checking protocol above the physical layer, and if this protocol detects and demands re-transmission of 10 bits out of every 1000 in the original transmission, then the throughput would have dropped down to 990 bits per second.

If the channel gets subjected to increased noise, thus requiring additional re-transmissions, the throughput drops further.

---

To be a bit (*more*) pedantic: Any error detection and re-transmission request protocol would typically require additional bits of header / ECC information, thus forming an overhead on the channel bit rate. This would bring throughput down further, compared to the raw bit rate.

Comment: An interface can also have addressing (sending a destination and sender address with the data), protocol identification (usually for higher levels of the network stack like TCP?), and management (e.g., acknowledgment message components and sequence numbers to support out of order delivery of packets) overhead.

Comment: I would perhaps use a term like "conveyed", rather than "received", since the latter term can be ambiguous in cases involving multiple transmitters, receivers, repeaters, etc.  In some cases, the purpose of a channel may be to provide a stream of information which any interested entity can start receiving at any time.  Such any information may be part of a channel's throughput even if the number of recipients happens to be zero (since the purpose was to ensure that anyone who was interested would get that information, and such purpose was accomplished).

Comment: @supercat Fair point - You just out-pedanted me :-)

Comment: @Paula Those overheads, while they exist, are perhaps at a higher layer than the spirit of the question indicated. Just my view.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Anindo's answer. Just to give a quick example using UART/RS232 communication:

Assume using UART communication with the following frame format
1 start bit
8 data bits
1 stop bit
no parity

Depending on the **bitrate** (9600 bit/s for example) your **throughput** will be 20% lower, because 2 out of every 10 bits are overhead (no usable information).

**bitrate** = 9600 bit/s
**throughput** = 7680 bit/s (or transmitting 960 bytes of usable information per second)

Comment: Thanks Revi, example made it further clear to Anindo's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Bitrate is a solid measure, throughput is application/protocol-dependent and subject to the vagaries of the marketing department.

Comment: I disagree. Bitrate tells you nothing about the amount of useful data per unit that can actually be transferred by the end application that needs to use the communication channel.

Comment: In other words, bitrate could just be the throughput of a single port. :)

Comment: @AndrejaKo - I didn't say it told you about the amount of useful data transferred, but it *does* tell you a solid measure of the number of bits transferred per second. All terms are subject to misuse by the marketing department, but bitrate is usually at least something you could measure reliably with a scope or similar.